# Homework: Angular Acceleration from Net Torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, torque, moment-of-inertia

I have the correct answer but don't know how that is the correct one. My answers were way off which indicates I am missing something big but don't know what. [image]

Now the 4 torques are: t1=6.175, t2=.3005, t3=0, and t4=0.

[image]

As you can see I was way off. I took the 4 torques and made t1 negative and added t2 as positive since t1 is directing in the negative direction (clockwise). I then tried 3 solutions:

- dividing that by the mass
- dividing by the moment of inertia: mass * length^2
- dividing by the mass times length

All the answers were way off. I thought it was supposed to be F=ma? Why doesn't this apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are way off in your thinking, and your 3 'tries' show that you are blindly guessing what is going on here.  I think you need to go back to the basics of torque and rotational motion.

The question asks you to find the angular acceleration $\alpha$ about the centre of mass (CM).  This is related to net torque $\tau$ and moment of inertia $I$ by $\tau = I\alpha$.

Torque is force times perpendicular distance from the pivot (CM). Forces $F_3$ and $F_4$ act through the CM so they provide no torque about CM and can be ignored.

The perpendicular distance of $F_1$ from CM is $\frac12L = 0.65m$.  The perpendicular distance of $F_2$ from CM is $\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}=0.1202m$.  So the net torque on the rod is
$\tau = 9.5\times0.65 - 2.5\times0.1202 = 5.8745Nm$
clockwise.

The moment of inertia of the rod about its centre is
$I=\frac{1}{12}ML^2=\frac{1}{12}\times1.7\times1.3^2=0.2394kgm^2$.
The angular acceleration is
$\alpha=\frac{\tau}{I}=\frac{5.8745}{0.2394}=24.5rad/s^2$.

Comment: I saw that in my homework that it some examples with 1/12. Why 1/12? That sounds like a very arbitrary number to use, but I have seen it around when I was looking online.

Comment: @JosiahL. The the number $\frac{1}{12}$ is not chosen arbitrarily.  As Floris explains, it is the factor you get when you calculate moment of inertia for the rod about its centre, just as the volume of a sphere contains the factor $\frac43$.  I think you need to review the basics of this topic.

Comment: I understand that 1/12 is used for a rectangular plate but don't you need to multiply by a^2 + b^2 instead of just L?

Answer (score 1):

They ask you for the angular acceleration $\alpha$, not the linear acceleration. I could not understand what you did, but you know that torque $\tau=I \alpha$, to find $\alpha$ only divide the torque you have by the moment of inertia $I=mL^2/12$ which corresponds to the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) of a rod around its center of mass.

Comment: Right. The factor 12 is exactly the factor by which the second guess was off. Moment of inertia is $mL^2$ if all the mass is a distance $L$ from the axis of rotation - but here no mass is further than $\frac12 L$ from the axis, and most of it is closer. Hence the factor $\frac{1}{12}$ which can be found from first principles (integration), or from tables (memorized).